# Does the Default theme of Wordpress like 2016, 2017 and 2019 uses Walker_Nav_Menu Class

Tags: menus, themes, walker

I want to know if these themes uses Walker_Nav_Menu class. As I open the files I can't see a Walker_Nav_Class or I could not find it. And I want to know what they use to display the Menu and Submenus. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we create a sub menu for the parent menu, the wp_nav_menu() generate the sub menu's with ul li tag, the ul tag contains the class of 'sub-menu'. In style they written the design for submenus

Answer (score 0):

They just use the default markup. You only need to define your own walker class if you’re changing the markup from the default. Believe it or not, but it’s perfectly possible to create menus without Bootstrap!

The only exceptions to the default menu markup is that some of the default themes, like Twenty Nineteen, use the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter to add SVG social icons to its social links menu, and SVG icons for the dropdown indicators. But this does not involve a custom walker class.

Comment: Where could I found the walker_nav_menu_start_el()?

Comment: Type it in to Google. Literally first result: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/

Comment: I found it on icon-functions.php file. Thank you